# Creating KPI's based on list field items

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list (eg: sales) with some fields. I want to create a kpi for sales list based on the particular field of the list.

For example, I have a field called value in that list. If that value equals 100, I want to show green and between 80 to 100, I need to show yellow and less than 80 red.

I am not able to create kpi based on the list field values, I am able to create based on the total list items count.

How can I do this....

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, its about how visually represent some values from list as KPIs.

Easiest way is to use complete controls, for example it could be DevExpress controls or Telerik or any other

For examples from DevExpress controls:
http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxPivotGridDemos/Templates/CellTemplates.aspx
http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/Live.aspx

From Telerik:

http://sharepoint.telerik.com/reporting/Pages/default.aspx

Another way is to use reporting engines to generate reports with graphics and diagrams. There also many reporting engines. For example when speaking about Microsoft stack, than MS SQL Service + Reporting Services and maybe with cubes and MS Analysis services.

So there is MSDN article on KPIs, reporting service and KPIs color indication
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283116.aspx

There are many ways not listed here, even build a custom grid control using Silverlight. All depends from requirements.